# How to login to mongodb(through pymongo) remotely and get output of db.serverStatus()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How to connect to a `mongodb` host remotely by specifying Username, Password, Hostname and also how to get `db.serverStatus()` output through `pymongo` ???

"I have commented the `bind_ip` in `**mongod.conf*` file, so that it allows remote connection"

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import MongoClient

connection=MongoClient(???)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a sample code:

```
import pymongo

MONGO_HOST = ''
MONGO_PORT = <PORT>
MONGO_DB=''
MONGO_USER='' 
MONGO_PASS=''

def get_mongo_db():
    con=pymongo.Connection(MONGO_HOST,MONGO_PORT)
    db=con[MONGO_DB]
    try:
        db.authenticate(MONGO_USER,MONGO_PASS)
    except:
        return None
    return db
```

Attention, if your mongo doesn't open auth (`--auth`), you needn't to auth, but it's recommended to open auth for security.

then, you can use `db` for more ops, as you said, `db.serverStatus()` (I haven't tried, maybe a little different)

Comment: Remote connection worked..!!!! Thanks........ But `db.serverStatus()' won't work directly in python...

Comment: client = pymongo.MongoClient()
client.admin.command('serverStatus')

Comment: DOESNT WORK: module 'pymongo' has no attribute 'Connection'